# WCF Client error using 'Basic128Sha256Rsa15'

Tags: wcf, sha256

I get the following error when moving from using SHA1 to SHA256 encryption via my WCF client-side config file. This is for a .NET 3.5 client running on a Windows 2003 server. 
I've implemented changes related to using SHA256 for SAML data found [here](http://www.componentspace.com/Forums/30/SHA256-XML-Signature-Support)

Snippet from my app.config:

```
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="HAServiceBrokerSOAP11BindingHewitt">
      <security defaultAlgorithmSuite="Basic128Sha256Rsa15"
```

Error message I receive in client error log:

System.InvalidOperationException: The binding ('CustomBinding', 'http://tempuri.org/') has been configured with a security algorithm suite 'Basic128Sha256Rsa15' that is not supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got things working. I'll post my resolution in case others land here via a search. 
One thing I tried that didn't work for me but may work for someone else is to use the Common Language Runtime version 4.0. CLR version 2.0 is what is used with .NET 3.5 assemblies. Here are the lines I added to my config file just after the  element:

```html
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
        <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
   </startup>
```

What finally worked for me was to upgrade the code from VS 2008 .NET 3.5 to VS 2010 .NET 4.0 and recompile the entire assembly. .NET 4.0 is not supported in VS 2008. .NET 4.0 assemblies use the CLR 4.0 version.